Have a Specific Folder show up when using Saveas showing Scanned Documents & FAX Folders
My Question is Similar to "How to change the default folder used for documents scanned with Windows Fax and Scan?"
The "Save As..." Drop-down from Excel shows Folders within "Document" such as "Scanned Documents" and "FAX". I would like to ADD a Specific folder so I can Easily Save To that folder when doing an Excel Save, apparently ZOOM was added by the Creators of ZOOM, but I Can Not Figure out how this was Accomplished.
Please Help

In Excel 365 (and perhaps earlier) it's possible to pin a folder
to the Save As page, like this:

Use Save As to save once to that folder
Now use Save As again and click on Recent
Hover the cursor over the folder and a pin will appear to the
right of the folder name
Click on the pin icon.

From now on, this folder will appear under "Pinned" in the Save As dialog.
